# applicationDidEnterBackground not running

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am putting this in my ViewController.m file and when my app enters the background the `NSLog` is never called.

Can anyone explain why?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"Application entered background state.");

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a method from `UIApplicationDelegate` to be called in a class that isn't the app delegate?

Answer (score 3):

This is app's delegate method. Put it in the object implementing the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol which is by default app's delegate class created for you when you start a new project.

Or use the **notification center** to get notified about an event of switching to the background. Just register your view controller as an observer of `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`. It's sent when entering the background.

#### Example

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(handleDidEnterBackgroundNotification:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: How could I call a method from my VC in my delegate? I need to call a method before my app enters the background.

Comment: You can keep a reference to your view controller in the app delegate and just call it.

Comment: @reecon The updated answer to use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in the view controller is MUCH better than keeping a reference to the controller in the app delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy, I know, I just realised that and updated the answer. Anyways it all depends. If the OP has a single view application then it does not make big difference.

Comment: It's matter of ownership. The logic belongs in the class that should know what do when the app goes in the background.